# adding cutom types to variables in python function

Tags: python-3.x, typescript, function, types

In typescript i have the option to do something like this:

```
    async tempFunction(vartA:'abc'|'dfe'){
    let x = vartA
}
```

How can i do something similar in Python? (to add specific types to variable within the function definition)
Of course tried the following, but it seems that it doesn't accept it:

```
def tempFunction(vartA:'abc' or 'dfe'):
    pass
```

is there any override / alternative method to implement it?

Comment: `from typing import Union` and then `def tempFunction(vartA: Union['abc', 'dfe']):`. https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Union

Comment: ok, so the method is:    def set_time(self, time_type: Union['before', 'after']):
        pass

i'm getting from pycharm: "Unresovled reference for "before""

Comment: What are the possible types that `time_type` can be?

Comment: in this case, just two types of strings: 'before' and 'after'.

Comment: Ooh I see. I misunderstood and thought you were referring to different types. For that you can use `from typing import Literal` and use `Literal['before', 'after']` in the same way. https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/typing.html#typing.Literal

Comment: I should note that this is new in python 3.8.

Comment: it almost matches my request. is there any option to:
1. autocomplete
2. warn about improper types? (or should i implement it myself?)
3. multiple types:
is there any ovverride to somehow use multiple types ?
for example:
def set_time(self, time_type: Literal['before', 'after',str,5,'int']):